# EKS Kubernetes Cluster Upgrade 1.25

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, podsecuritypolicy, kyverno

Due to the deprecation of Mandatory PodSecurityPolicy, we transitioned to Kyverno for policy management following the upgrade to V1.25. However, challenges have arisen in terms of component communication after the implementation. If anyone has successfully addressed similar issues in their implementation, we would greatly value your insights.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and responses.

We have tried to use the Kyverno to place the PSP in place after upgrading the EKS to 1.25. Expecting any insight if someone faced the same issue, and how it solved.